# What is this INOP instrument and when is it safe to fly with INOP instruments?

Tags: flight-instruments

I flew ZRH->LHR on BA0711 today on G-EUOG. I noticed through the cabin door one of the instruments had a yellow INOP sticker across it (see photo). Which instrument was it? I am presuming the instrument has a backup, and the backup was operative, but I had thought the purpose of an backup was so that it could be used if the primary failed *in flight*? Or is the instrument just 'not important'? What are the rules re flying with INOP instruments?
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what instrument it is, but the ironic part is that the sticker makes it legal to fly with the INOP instrument. Without the sticker it would be against the rules (at least in the US). This includes instruments that go INOP in flight, which is why some aircraft have sticky notes or INOP stickers on board.

Comment: In case it helps someone, G-EUOG seems to be an Airbus A319-131.

Comment: @RonBeyer it's quite possible for something to ground the aircraft when INOP, would still be marked just as a reference for maintenance and a warning to other crew to not fly the aircraft.

Comment: @RonBeyer Well, it's not as stupid as it sounds.  A big INOP sticker makes it obvious that the instrument is not functioning.  Without a sticker what is to stop a pilot from forgetting that the intstrument is broken and then reacting inappropriately to the (incorrect) information displayed?

Comment: @jwenting I don't think I suggested that it wasn't the case, I've grounded aircraft myself because of INOP equipment, and made sure it was marked properly for the maintenance people.

Comment: @J... I didn't say it was stupid to mark it out in flight, or mean to suggest that. The "ironic" part for me is that if you are flying and an instrument goes INOP, you may be in violation of a FAR unless you mark it out, but who is going to verify that?

Comment: @RonBeyer Well, it's like anything else.  It's in the pilots' best interest to mark it out because, first and foremost, it's they who will end up making mistakes with it.  In most cases maybe nobody would notice but I imagine it's not the kind of thing you want to let slide and have come out in an NTSB investigation when something does go wrong.  You could say the same thing about skipping checklists - who is going to verify that they were done?  If nothing goes wrong, maybe nobody... I don't think it's ironic that people should follow checklists, though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is a standby display, specifically a DDRMI (Digital Distance Radio Magnetic Indicator).

The aircraft can be dispatched with inoperative equipment. The process is controlled by a Minimum Equipment List (MEL). The operator will have an MEL for each type of aircraft in their fleet. The MEL is approved by the regulatory authority (FAA, CAA, etc.) and specifies what may be inop and associated restrictions.

I don't know what the BA MEL for the A319 is, but here's a snip from the FAA's Master MEL (MMEL), which is the guidance for each operator to use when creating their MEL.

[image: FAA MMEL for A319]

Following this guidance, the MEL would say you can dispatch with the DDRMI INOP if the FAR equipment minimums are met. That (at least in the US) is along the lines of "navigational equipment necessary for the planned flight".

Answer (score 19):

> I am presuming the instrument has a backup, and the backup was
>   operative

The "INOP" instrument itself is a backup. It is a navigation instrument which combines a compass, VOR needles and ADF needles. This backup instrument is an analog version which runs on 70s tech. It is rarely (if ever) needed, only intending to be used when all cockpit computers fail, which is exceptionally rare. The modern version uses computers and the results are displayed on the screens you see.

> What are the rules re flying with INOP instruments?

As others have stated, the "Minimum Equipment List" is a document that lists what equipment is essential for an aircraft to be dispatched.

Besides safety, dispatch rate is another reason why there is redundancy in an airliner cockpit. With systems as complex as this (the manual of a modern airliner is thousands of pages long), failures are not unusual. It is more economical to design an aircraft that can still fly with *some* instruments / systems inoperative rather one which requires everything to be 100% working.

Answer (score 12):

The instrument is a backup VOR gauge. It's there in case manual radio navigation is needed (hardly in a modern airliner) AND the displays are not working.

As it's not an instrument that's vital for getting the aircraft on the ground safely, it's no problem if it's declared INOP (there is probably a maximum time period for it to be marked as such before repairs are required).

Answer (score 5):

Every aircraft has a MMEL (Master Minimum Equipment List) and a MEL (Minimum Equipment List).
While the MMELs are published by the producer of the aircraft, MELs are generated by the companies flying these airplanes. Every company may have different MEL for the same aircraft. This MELs cannot be shorter than the MMEL.
If that malfunctioning or inoperative equipment is in the MEL that aircraft cannot fly without special permissions.

This is the basic information. For more information you can read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_minimum_equipment_list) or FAA, JAR or EU OPS publications.